# Why do my UITableView cells not update correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have this weird issue and I can't seem to find out why.

Here's the deal; I have a `UITableView` with some cells which the data comes from an array, there is a button in my cell, once pressed it displays new rows which are part of the cell. The cells are a dark shade of colour, like everything else in my `UITableView`, I have triple checked the storyboard for any white colours, but still my cell displays a small white line to the left of the separator, the line disappears when the cell goes out of the viewport on the top but appears again when the cell went out of the viewport on the bottom.

Here is what I see once I press the button to show the other rows, and also what I see when the cells were scrolled out of the viewport at the bottom. 
[image: Once I pressed the expand button]

And here is what I see once the cells were scrolled out of the viewport at the top.
[image: Once they were scrolled out of the viewport at the top]

Here is the code for when I press the button.

```
- (IBAction)onGroupButtonClick:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    showSubRows = YES;

    [contactList setNeedsDisplay];
    [contactList setNeedsLayout];
    [contactList reloadData];
}
```

And here is the code for the indented rows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(showSubRows) {
        subRow *subRow = (subRow*)data[indexPath.section];

        [button setAlpha:0.0f];
        // Fill vars..
    }
}
```

I hope I have provided enough information.

Thanks.

Comment: check if your separator style is none if not, try using 
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: The white mark looks like it is a hangover from the separator margin when there was no indent. It is probably related to how you define your cells. A simple work around is to turn separators off and add a 1 point transparent view across the bottom of the cell prototype, which will give you the impression of separation between cells. How are you indenting just now? You really need something that draws over the indent area.

Comment: Also why set the alpha of the button to 0.0. Better to set it as hidden?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I fixed it by setting the separator to none, and adding my own. Not really a fix but more of a work around.